# Create executable file for comand line Linux

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

When ever I log into Linux I usually go straight to the same folder i was wondering if in stead of typing in:

```
$cd Document/..../..../..../..../....
```

I could create an executable so I could just type `./csFolder` and it would go straight there.

Comment: Read about links. There are at least 2 kind of those: "hard links" and "soft links". They are a little (very little) like windows shortcuts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a shell function in your `.bashrc` and restart your terminal:

```
csf() {
  cd Document/..../..../..../..../....
}
```

Whenever you want to go to that directory, you just run `csf`.

Answer (score 2):

Yo can do a symlink

`ln -s /path/to/file /path/to/symlink`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other options (though if you use the function/alias option you want to use an absolute path to the target directory so it works from wherever you happen to be) you can use the environment variable `CDPATH` to help with this if you have a location you often go to from various other locations.

From the [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html#tag_20_14_08):

> CDPATH
>
> A -separated list of pathnames that refer to directories. The cd utility shall use this list in its attempt to change the directory, as described in the DESCRIPTION. An empty string in place of a directory pathname represents the current directory. If CDPATH is not set, it shall be treated as if it were an empty string.

Which means that if you set `CDPATH` to the parent of your target directory you can just use `cd dirname` from anywhere and go directly to the directory you wanted to be in.