# Bash Scripting - to manage server navigation

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I am writing some bash scripts to make life easier when managing around an application.

The scripts really just change directories to my most common locations which saves a huge amount of time.

Currently I have my script in my users .bash_profile and this works nicely.

i.e.

```
#SHORTENED COMMANDS
alias flushBash='source ~/.bash_profile'
alias editBash='sudo nano /home/gtec/.bash_profile'

#DIRECTORIES
alias gost='cd /var/www/location/of/directory'
```

From command line I just type: gost and I am taken to the directory of my choice. Now the above is fine if I am the only one using the server however, eventually I will need sys admins etc. so I figured I would write a script to help third parties along.

So I added a script to my bash:

```
#SCRIPTS
alias go='. /home/me/scripts/go.sh'
```

And the idea is that the user types: "go" into the command line, and it then returns a list of options.

This is what I have thus far:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "Where do you want to go? home, anc-p, anc-s, auto-p, auto-s"
read -p "Enter a location :" location
if [$location = home]
then
  cd /home/gtec 
else
echo "Noting to do"
fi
```

When I run the above it outputs:

```
Where do you want to go? home, anc-p, anc-s, auto-p, auto-s
Enter a location :home
[home: command not found
Noting to do
```

and when I type in "home" it returns: home:command not found...

What I am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You may want to look into the `CDPATH` variable (see note in the docs for [`cd`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-cd) and my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31571752/258523)) instead of a custom script like this. And if you **do** keep this you should make it a shell function and not a script (to save loading it from disk repeatedly).

Comment: By the way, using `cd` in a script as you are here, will change your directory _just for the script_.  Once the script, and the subshell it runs in, terminate, you'll be back in the parent shell and still in the original directory.  This is another reason for coding it as a function instead, as that runs without spawning a subshell.

Comment: @rojomoke That's true, you can get around that problem by sourcing the script instead of calling it directly, that keeps the execution in the same shell, e.g. `$> . shell_utils.bsh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer according to comments by Etan Reisner, original inaccurate one preserved below.**

The main problem is syntactical: you need spaces around the square brackets of the `if`. Furthermore, you should always quote your variables in case they contain whitespace characters. Solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "Where do you want to go? home, anc-p, anc-s, auto-p, auto-s"
read -p "Enter a location : " location
if [ "$location" = "home" ]
then
  cd /home/gtec 
else
  echo "Nothing to do"
fi
```

---

Original, inaccurate answer for reference:

You have 2 mistakes in your if: firstly, you assign with `=` instead of testing with `==`, secondly you're missing whitespace. Here's what it should look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "Where do you want to go? home, anc-p, anc-s, auto-p, auto-s"
read -p "Enter a location :" location
if [ $location == home ]
then
  cd /home/gtec 
else
echo "Nothing to do"
fi
```

The inaccuracy lied in (1) suggesting that `==` is the only option and (2) omitting the double quotes.

Comment: The test operator is, in fact, `=` and **not** `==`. `==` is a compat thing that some shells (namely bash, etc.) support but is not spec. The spacing is entirely correct but you really need to quote `"$location"`.

Comment: @Etan, thanks for the tip. However, `man bash` tells me that "= may be used in place of == for strict POSIX compliance." for testing string equality. This somehow tells me that at least for `bash`, `==` is the proper way to do. And it works perfectly fine for me as in the answer, without quotes. What is up with that?

Comment: Yes, `==` works (in bash) but it isn't spec. So why use it? For `[[` you **do** need `==` though. But that's because `[[` is already a bash-ism. And it works without quotes because you entered a single word. Try entering `foo bar` and see what happens. Note again that for `[[` you **do not** need the quotes as `[[` is, again, a bash-ism with special rules (such as being smarter about word splitting).

Comment: OK, I was only thinking about single words (as in the list of expected options). I'll change my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the things you are comparing.

```
if [ "$location" == "home" ]
```

Comment: The quoting here is correct (and the suggestion to use it is also correct) but that is not the fix for the OPs problem. (This answer works it just misses explaining what the *actual* fix here is.)